# Spring basic security confiugred userid/password not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Our application is based on Spring-boot 2.0.   I've enabled basic security by adding the following dependency to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
<version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I also have added properties so that I can define my own userid and password for basic security, instead of the generated ones.  I defined them like this in /resources/applicaiton.properties file:

```
security.user.name=user1
security.user.password=pass1
```

When I startup my application, I can see that is still generates the password for me in the log.  Also, I am unable to login using user1/pass1 combination.  I can only successfully login with the user=user and password=generated-password-from-log file.

Why won't spring security allow me to login with user1/pass1?  What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those properties need the spring prefix.

```
spring.security.user.name=user # Default user name.
spring.security.user.password= # Password for the default user name.
```

If I want to configure something I often take a look at [this List](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for that useful link, too!